# How to make onclick function create images in the same div?

Tags: javascript

this code is part of an onclick function. the function supposed to show some calculation results and corresponded images in the div ("gallerym"). everything works but when the user clicks on the button to trigger the onclick multiple times it will create more divs (gallerym),

I was able to make the function work only once with: this.onclick=null but now the user is restricted only to one click (after which he will have to refresh the page to use it again )

my question is: HOW TO MAKE SURE THAT THE FUNCTION WILL CREATE THE IMAGES IN THE SAME DIV WITHOUT CREATING NEW DIVS?

THANK YOU!

```
var inputgal = document.getElementById('cmbar').value;
if (inputgal > 10 && inputgal <= 100) {
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = "../images/gallery/10cmto100cmm600x600.jpg";
   var src = document.getElementById("gallerym");
   src.appendChild(img);
} else if (inputgal > 100 && inputgal <= 1000) {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "../images/gallery/1mto10mm600x600.jpg";
      var src = document.getElementById("gallerym");
      src.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "img" to "IMG" and append the child in one statement instead of assigning it to a variable. This solution worked for me here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_src

```
var inputgal = document.getElementById('cmbar').value;

if (inputgal > 10 && inputgal <= 100) {
   var img = document.createElement("IMG");
   img.src = "...";
   document.getElementById("gallerym").appendChild(img);
} else if (inputgal > 100 && inputgal <= 1000) {
      var img = document.createElement("IMG");
      img.src = "...";
      document.getElementById("gallerym").appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the tip , but i does completely the same . the moment i click on this function one more time it will create a new div just under the existing one.

Comment: Can you post your entire onclick function, along with the html this is targeting? I'm getting expected results when using the w3 environment.

Comment: Thank you for this , this is my entire code for the function

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when you attempt to use the function multiple times? Obvious question, but you don't have more than one id set to "gallerym" anywhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

///html//

```
      <div id="gallerym"> <img id ="gallerymain" src = "default image.jpg" >
      </div


       //JAVASCRIPT//


  if (inputgal > 10 && inputgal <= 100) {

       document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = "image1.jpg"  } 

  else if (inputgal > 100 && inputgal <= 1000) {

       document.getElementById("gallerymain").src = "image2.jog"  }
```